# The method findViewById(int) is undefined and The constructor MediaController is undefined

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-videoview

I'm creating this fragment to stream video but I get two error stated that the method findViewById(int) is undefined and the constructor MediaController is undefined.

```
public class CommunityFragment extends Fragment  {

VideoView videoview;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View  v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_community, container, false);
    VideoView videoView=(VideoView)v.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);

    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    String str="http://202.73.9.10:1935/live2/smil:kctv_all.smil/playlist.m3u8";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("first_uri");


    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.start();
    return  v;
}
}
```

Comment: I move all into the onCreateView, but now it state that "can't play the video"

Answer (score 0):

you have

```
VideoView videoView=(VideoView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
```

and

```
videoview = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
```

if VideoView belongs to the activity the first line is kind of ok, and you can delete the second one. It VideoView belongs to the Fragment, you can use

```
videoview = (VideoView)getView().findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
```

and get rid of the first one

Comment: it works, I'm using the third one but the constructor MediaController is still undefined.

Answer (score 0):

When using fragmet, please place your code and all methods in OnCreateView, 
because like in activity on create, fragment has his own implementation when fragment created.

for example:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_timeline, container, false);

    initViews(v);


    return v;
}
```

My Init View function:

```
private void initViews(View v)
{

    profileName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.profileName);

    profilePic = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.profilePic);

    profileNameSymbol= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.profileNameSymbol);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have this:

`MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(getActivity().getApplicationContext());`

A few lines later, you are doing this:

`mediaController = new MediaController(this);`

`this` is a Fragment, and a Fragment is not a valid `Context`. You would use `getActivity()` instead of `this`, but as mentioned, this line is already unnecessary.

Comment: I edit the code above but now I get error state that it can't play the video.

Comment: Please refer to the documentation for MediaPlayer (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) and also the Media Playback guide (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html). Media players follow a specific state machine and you must ensure that the media is prepared before you can start playing it.